# Program stops unexpectedly when I use gettimeofday() in an infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, gettimeofday

I've written a code to ensure each loop of while(1) loop to take specific amount of time (in this example 10000µS which equals to 0.01 seconds). The problem is this code works pretty well at the start but somehow stops after less than a minute. It's like there is a limit of accessing linux time. For now, I am initializing a boolean variable to make this time calculation run once instead infinite. Since performance varies over time, it'd be good to calculate the computation time for each loop. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
void some_function(){
struct timeval tstart,tend;
while (1){
   gettimeofday (&tstart, NULL);
   ...
   Some computation
   ...
   gettimeofday (&tend, NULL);
   diff = (tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec)*1000000L+(tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec);
   usleep(10000-diff);
   }
}
```

Comment: When it stops , is there any message displayed?

Comment: Check for `diff` overflow.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No,there is no message displayed.

Comment: What happens when `diff` is bigger than 10000? Even if your calculation always takes less than 10000us doesn't mean that the system will run it all the time. The system may choose to run other processes for quite some time before giving back control to your program. So you can easily end up with diff being much greater than 10000. Using the wall clock for timing is not always a good idea. (if you wonder what happens, the argument to `usleep` is very often an unsigned number).

Comment: Add some debug `printf` calls.

Comment: @Art When diff is bigger than 10000 program sleeps forever.

Comment: In this case you get an underflow and the number passed to `usleep` will be really large, which of course means that the programm will also sleep very long.

Comment: @venth1a Are you sure it's forever? Did you test it? I'm pretty sure it won't be forever but somewhere around 71 minutes.

Comment: @Art I've tested the negative case. After I've waited program to respond in 5-10 minutes, I decided to stop it.

Comment: The `usleep` parameter is unsigned, so it cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the computation you make to get the difference is wrong:

```
diff = (tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec)*1000000L+(tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec);
```

You are mixing different integer types, missing that `tv_usec` can be an `unsigned` quantity, which your are substracting from another `unsigned` and can overflow.... after that, you get as result a full second plus a quantity that is around `4.0E09usec`.  This is some 4000sec. or more than an hour.... aproximately.  It is better to check if there's some carry, and in that case, to increment `tv_sec`, and then substract `10000000` from `tv_usec` to get a proper positive value.

I don't know the implementation you are using for `struct timeval` but the most probable is that `tv_sec` is a `time_t` (this can be even 64bit) while `tv_usec` normally is just a `unsigned` 32 bit value, as it it not going to go further from `1000000`.

Let me illustrate... suppose you have elapsed 100ms doing calculations.... and this happens to occur in the middle of a second.... you have

```
tstart.tv_sec = 123456789; tstart.tv_usec = 123456;
tend.tv_sec = 123456789; tend.tv_usec = 223456;
```

when you substract, it leads to:

```
tv_sec = 0; tv_usec = 100000;
```

but let's suppose you have done your computation while the second changes

```
tstart.tv_sec = 123456789; tstart.tv_usec = 923456;
tend.tv_sec =  123456790; tend.tv_usec = 23456;
```

the time difference is again 100msec, but now, when you calculate your expression you get, for the first part, 1000000 (one full second) but, after substracting the second part you get `23456 - 923456 =*=> 4294067296` (*) with the overflow.
so you get to `usleep(4295067296)` or `4295s.` or `1h 11m` more.
I think you have not had enough patience to wait for it to finish... but this is something that can be happening to your program, depending on how `struct timeval` is defined.

A proper way to make carry to work is to reorder the summation to do all the additions first and then the substractions.  This forces casts to signed integers when dealing with `signed` and `unsigned` together, and prevents a negative overflow in `unsigned`s.

```
diff = (tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec) * 1000000 + tstart.tv_usec - tend.tv_usec;
```

which is parsed as

```
diff = (((tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec) * 1000000) + tstart.tv_usec) - tend.tv_usec;
```

Answer (score 2):

> from man-page of usleep

```
 #include <unistd.h>

 int usleep(useconds_t usec);
```

usec is unsigned int, now guess what happens when diff is > 10000 in below line

```
 usleep(10000-diff);
```